Jquery popup open and closes all at the same time, need to make it independent
This is the popup
  <div class="popup-overlay">
  <div class="popup-content">
  <button class="close">X</button> 
  <div>'.do_shortcode('[contact-form-7 id="14801" title="PDF Download"]').'</div>
  <div class="download_link"><a href="'.$a['dl_url'].'" download>Download</a></div>  
  </div>
  </div>
  

this is the button
<div class="download-brochure"><a class="open">'.$a['dl_btn_title'].'</a></div>

this is placed inside a shortcode function so that I can place it anywhere
The issue here is that when I add two two or more shortcodes in a page, it opens all of them and closes all at the same time
Here is my jquery code
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function(){

jQuery(".open").on("click", function() {
    jQuery(".popup-overlay, .popup-content").addClass("active");
});

jQuery(".close").on("click", function() {
    jQuery(".popup-overlay, .popup-content").removeClass("active");
});

});
</script>

I don't know how to make it independent to where I put it, I just want to make the popup work only for that shortcode, so if there are 3 shortcodes then 3 popup on click independently, thank you for any help
This worked for me
  <div class="popup-overlay po'.$a['dl_pop_id'].'">
  <div class="popup-content">
  <button class="close close'.$a['dl_pop_id'].'">X</button> 
  <div>'.do_shortcode('[contact-form-7 id="14801" title="PDF Download"]').'</div>
  <div class="download_link"><a href="'.$a['dl_url'].'" download>Download</a></div>  
  </div>
  </div>



<div class="download-brochure"><a class="open open'.$a['dl_pop_id'].'">'.$a['dl_btn_title'].'</a></div>

and made my script like this
if ( jQuery(".open").hasClass("open1") ) {

    jQuery(".open1").on("click", function() {
        jQuery(".popup-overlay.po1").addClass("active");
    });
    jQuery(".close.close1").on("click", function() {
        jQuery(".popup-overlay.po1").removeClass("active");
    });
}
if ( jQuery(".open").hasClass("open2") ) {

    jQuery(".open2").on("click", function() {
        jQuery(".popup-overlay.po2").addClass("active");
    });
    jQuery(".close.close2").on("click", function() {
        jQuery(".popup-overlay.po2").removeClass("active");
    });
}
if ( jQuery(".open").hasClass("open3") ) {

    jQuery(".open3").on("click", function() {
        jQuery(".popup-overlay.po3").addClass("active");
    });
    jQuery(".close.close3").on("click", function() {
        jQuery(".popup-overlay.po3").removeClass("active");
    });
}
if ( jQuery(".open").hasClass("open4") ) {

    jQuery(".open4").on("click", function() {
        jQuery(".popup-overlay.po4").addClass("active");
    });
    jQuery(".close.close4").on("click", function() {
        jQuery(".popup-overlay.po4").removeClass("active");
    });
}
if ( jQuery(".open").hasClass("open5") ) {

    jQuery(".open5").on("click", function() {
        jQuery(".popup-overlay.po5").addClass("active");
    });
    jQuery(".close.close5").on("click", function() {
        jQuery(".popup-overlay.po5").removeClass("active");
    });
}
if ( jQuery(".open").hasClass("open6") ) {

    jQuery(".open6").on("click", function() {
        jQuery(".popup-overlay.po6").addClass("active");
    });
    jQuery(".close.close6").on("click", function() {
        jQuery(".popup-overlay.po6").removeClass("active");
    });
}
if ( jQuery(".open").hasClass("open7") ) {

    jQuery(".open7").on("click", function() {
        jQuery(".popup-overlay.po7").addClass("active");
    });
    jQuery(".close.close7").on("click", function() {
        jQuery(".popup-overlay.po7").removeClass("active");
    });
}
if ( jQuery(".open").hasClass("open8") ) {

    jQuery(".open8").on("click", function() {
        jQuery(".popup-overlay.po8").addClass("active");
    });
    jQuery(".close.close8").on("click", function() {
        jQuery(".popup-overlay.po8").removeClass("active");
    });
}
if ( jQuery(".open").hasClass("open9") ) {

    jQuery(".open9").on("click", function() {
        jQuery(".popup-overlay.po9").addClass("active");
    });
    jQuery(".close.close9").on("click", function() {
        jQuery(".popup-overlay.po9").removeClass("active");
    });
}
if ( jQuery(".open").hasClass("open10") ) {

    jQuery(".open10").on("click", function() {
        jQuery(".popup-overlay.po10").addClass("active");
    });
    jQuery(".close.close10").on("click", function() {
        jQuery(".popup-overlay.po10").removeClass("active");
    });
}


Most simple solution, in my mind, is to set an extra class or data-attr and search for that on click to open and connect to the proper modal. Issue is obviously you are connecting to the same pop-up items on each .open or .close click, there is no differentiated values to choose from

hi @ViaTech I don't know much about jQuery and my brain is empty on things like this :-)

@FrancisAlvinTan You can add an id/ an attribute/ a class to differentiate the pop ups so you can pick which one is needed to open up. Or you can traverse from the button to the correct pop up. If you could provide complete code it'd be easier to make an answer to demonstrate.

Hi @LãNgọcHải I have updated my question with a code I made

@FrancisAlvinTan the code that you added made it ... way more confusing. Could you put the code into a runnable snippet instead of separating them? Also the problem is simply make buttons respectively for each pop up? If so I'll make an answer as demonstration.

@FrancisAlvinTan needs to know that you have the n number of pop-up HTML and the same n number of buttons to open them correspondingly (which actually not happening right now). Am I right?

Ok assuming that the elements could be anywhere you could take this approach this will only work for predefined number of popups
I added multiple popups and explanation
Approach 1
<!-- popup 1 we set overlay1 content1 close1 and open1 -->
<div class="popup-overlay1">
  <div class="popup-content1">
    <button class="close1">X</button>
    <div>
      '.do_shortcode('[contact-form-7 id="14801" title="PDF Download"]').'
    </div>
    <div class="download_link">
      <a href="'.$a['dl_url'].'" download>Download</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="download-brochure">
  <a class="open1">'.$a['dl_btn_title'].'</a>
</div>
<!-- popup 2 we set overlay2 content2 close2 and open2 -->
<div class="popup-overlay2">
  <div class="popup-content2">
    <button class="close2">X</button>
    <div>
      '.do_shortcode('[contact-form-7 id="14801" title="PDF Download"]').'
    </div>
    <div class="download_link">
      <a href="'.$a['dl_url'].'" download>Download</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="download-brochure3">
  <a class="open2">'.$a['dl_btn_title'].'</a>
</div>
<!-- popup 3 we set overlay3 content3 close3 and open3 -->
<div class="popup-overlay3">
  <div class="popup-content3">
    <button class="close3">X</button>
    <div>
      '.do_shortcode('[contact-form-7 id="14801" title="PDF Download"]').'
    </div>
    <div class="download_link">
      <a href="'.$a['dl_url'].'" download>Download</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="download-brochure"><a class="open3">'.$a['dl_btn_title'].'</a></div>

<script>
  jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    // Now that we already defined the numbers of the elements we can iterate over the ones that we built 1,2,3
    [1, 2, 3].forEach((popupNumber) => {
      // We construct the jquery calls with the appropiate numbers for open1, open2, and open3
      jQuery(`.open${popupNumber}`).on("click", function () {
        // We show the respective elements
        jQuery(
          `.popup-overlay${popupNumber}, .popup-content${popupNumber}`
        ).addClass("active");
      });

      // We construct the jquery calls with the appropiate numbers for close1, close2, and close3
      jQuery(`.close${popupNumber}`).on("click", function () {
        // We hide the respective elements
        jQuery(
          `.popup-overlay${popupNumber}, .popup-content${popupNumber}`
        ).removeClass("active");
      });
    });
  });
</script>

This is another approach (better IMO) but you need to create another wrapper html and put the overlay and the button in the same parent wrapper
Approach 2
<!-- We set a new parent (for first overlay and button) that will wrap overlay and button -->
<div className="common-parent">
  <div class="popup-overlay">
    <div class="popup-content">
      <button class="close">X</button>
      <div>
        '.do_shortcode('[contact-form-7 id="14801" title="PDF Download"]').'
      </div>
      <div class="download_link">
        <a href="'.$a['dl_url'].'" download>Download</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="download-brochure">
    <a class="open">'.$a['dl_btn_title'].'</a>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- We set a new parent (for second overlay and button) that will wrap overlay and button -->
<div className="common-parent">
  <div class="popup-overlay">
    <div class="popup-content">
      <button class="close">X</button>
      <div>
        '.do_shortcode('[contact-form-7 id="14801" title="PDF Download"]').'
      </div>
      <div class="download_link">
        <a href="'.$a['dl_url'].'" download>Download</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="download-brochure">
    <a class="open">'.$a['dl_btn_title'].'</a>
  </div>
</div>

<script>
  $(document).ready(function () {
    // we listen all clicks from class .open elements
    $(".open").on("click", function () {
      // this is getting the button that was clicked
      // closest go and find the closest parent with that class name
      // we find the overlay and show it
      $(this)
        .closest(".common-parent")
        .find(".popup-overlay")
        .addClass("active");
    });
    // we listen all clicks from class .close elements
    $(".close").on("click", function () {
      // this is getting the button that was clicked
      // closest go and find the closest parent with that class name
      // we find the overlay and hide it
      $(this)
        .closest(".common-parent")
        .find(".popup-overlay")
        .removeClass("active");
    });
  });
</script>


For approach 2 the parent could be anywhere but needs to be one parent per overlay and button
